# Make title="" on discord embed a hyperlink

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Ok so ive been trying for about an hour now but I can't seem to figure it out.

[image] <Image 1

[image] <Image 2

So I'm trying to make an embed like op.ggs once and I'm stuck getting font sizes and hyperlinks. in Image 1 where it says "Here is your op.gg search for Killogee" I want that to be hyperlink but that
`title = f'Here is your op.gg search for {playerign}',` and hyperlink doesn't work with title so I'm confused in what to do, something i tried was, if i just put the code `title= f'[Killogee - Summoner Stats - League of Legends](https://oce.op.gg/summoner/userName=Killogee)'` it will come up like

[image]

If this helps
Code:

```
if message.content.startswith('$player '): 
        playerign = (message.content.split('$player ')[1])

        playeropgg = discord.Embed(
          title = (f'Here is your op.gg search for {playerign}'),
          colour = discord.Colour.blue(),
          timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
        )

        playeropgg.set_thumbnail(url='https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/h-KHJTr-6zs_SUMgRzZt_41SMr5SSW41YeSvy-MTMfY/https/opgg-static.akamaized.net/icon/reverse.rectangle.png?width=1051&height=683')
        playeropgg.set_author(name='OP.GG Oceania')
        playeropgg.add_field(name='\u200b', value=f'**[{playerign} - Summoner Stats - League of Legends]**(https://oce.op.gg/summoner/userName={playerign.replace(" ", "%20")})', inline=False)
        playeropgg.set_footer(text=f'Searched for {message.author}')

        await message.channel.send(embed=playeropgg)
```

Answer (score 1):

all i need was to add `url = f'https://oce.op.gg/summoner/userName={playerign.replace(" ", "%20")}'` in

```
playeropgg = discord.Embed(
          title = (f'Here is your op.gg search for {playerign}'),
          colour = discord.Colour.blue(),
          timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
        )
```